# What was the first proof assistant with eta equality for records?

Tags: coq, agda, eta-equality

The Agda language supports eta equality for (non-(co)inductive) record types:

```hs
open import Agda.Builtin.Sigma
open import Agda.Builtin.Equality

eta : {A : Set} {B : A → Set} (x : Σ A B) → x ≡ (fst x , snd x)
eta x = refl
```

This was present since the first released of Agda 2 (see https://github.com/agda/agda/commit/1ac70d3ec0fc5151c71f9bdc8e8ebf8ea00ccd5c).

Likewise, Coq supports eta equality for records with primitive projections (but not for the unit type). However, primitive projections were only added to Coq in version 8.5, from 2016 (https://coq.inria.fr/news/coq-85-is-out.html).

My question: **What was the first proof assistant to feature eta-equality for record types?** Was there any language before Agda with this feature or was Agda really the first? Are there any publications that describe it?

Comment: I am not sure if this is the first (so I'm leaving a comment), but Nuprl has always supported the eta law for its sigma types; this goes back to 1985-ish, I suppose. But around the same time I think there was also an implementation of type theory in Gothenburg that I haven't been able to learn anything specific about. Maybe someone knows?

Comment: I was thinking more about systems that (are supposed to) have decidable conversion, but I didn't think of NuPRL so I believe this would be a valid answer.

Comment: I would say an historically important reference here is Abel and Coquand's _Untyped Algorithmic Equality for Martin-Löf’s Logical Framework with Surjective Pairs_. You have plenty of references there on how people have tried implementing η-equality for record types (or what they call strong sums).

Comment: @Meven: Ah excellent, that paper's related work section is indeed a very valuable resource. It pointed me in particular to this paper by Robin Adams from 2001, which is the earliest reference that I could find so far: https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=30a62485c9a340f3eaf8e11102539e53205ca08a

Comment: It's hard to find things about Automath - you should ask Freek directly. There are all sorts of wonders in there that people forget about.

Comment: I just found the following sentence in Thierry's 1991 paper on conversion checking: "It seems possible to extend the proof in the case where there is a dependent sum of types, and surjective pairing. The only changes are in the notion of weak head-normal form and the definition of => and <=>." So at least people were already considering the notion for a long time! So I really wonder why it took so long to get it into our implementations.